# Trouble with Expanding $Env:TEMP in start-process MSIEXEC

Tags: powershell

I have been unable to understand why the following command don't trigger the silent installation  of Power-Bi  -

```
Start-Process msiexec -wait -ArgumentList '/i $ENV:Temp\PBIDesktop_x64.msi /qn /norestart ACCEPT_EULA=1'
```

where as the following works -

```
Start-Process msiexec -wait -ArgumentList '/i C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PBIDesktop_x64.msi /qn /norestart ACCEPT_EULA=1
```

'

I am using an elevated ISE but the first command generates no errors and does nothing. I think that the `$ENV:TEMP` is not expanding. Please help.

regards,
Prateek

Answer (score 3):

Powershell won't extend anything in a string if you're using single-quoted-ticks instead of double quotes. So change your code to:

```
Start-Process msiexec -wait -ArgumentList "/i $ENV:Temp\PBIDesktop_x64.msi /qn /norestart ACCEPT_EULA=1"
```

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) describes the quotation rules.

In short:

```
> $i = 1
> "Double quotes: $i + $i"
Double quotes: 1 + 1
> 'Single quotes: $i + $i'
Single quotes: $i + $i
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer.